# What is Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto message in my debug console

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have recently upgraded to flutter v3, and I am seeing this message Flutter Web Bootstrap: Auto, sometimes Flutter Web Bootstrap: Programmatic in my debug console.
I did search for it but the results returned with bootstrap implementation for flutter.
I am not sure but I think it is related to how the app should load in flutter web.
I want to know in depth what this means.

Comment: might be https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99773

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before flutter 3.0 we have one `automatic` bootstrap strategy. Flutter 3.0 gives us more control on bootstraping (for example you may add some visualizaton during flutter initialization) so called `programmatic` strategy.

You can read more [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/web/initialization).